# How to Optimize Data Writes to Postgres with NextJS and Prisma on batch operations?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel

I'm working on a NextJS project where I need to optimize data writes to a Postgres database using Prisma, as this is one of my most significant usage costs in Vercel's storage. Currently, I'm considering different approaches to reduce the amount of data being written to the database. One approach I'm exploring is batching update operations to minimize overhead. However, I'm unsure if this will effectively reduce the "Postgres Written Data" metric. Can anyone provide insights or alternative strategies for optimizing data writes in this context?

```html
// Current approach: Individual updates / creates
mySchemaArray.map(async (schemaData) => {
  await prisma.mySchema.update({ where: {id: schemaData.id}, data: schemaData.data });
});
```

I have even written a bulkUpdate function that generates a single SQL query and then executes it with prisma.$queryRaw. It is much faster although not very flexible (if I want to query the objects by other fields instead of the id for instance), but I am still trying to figure out if this will reduce my "written data" because of lower overhead.

If there are any other strategies or best practices for optimizing data writes in a NextJS application using Prisma I would be very interested. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like this is more about understanding your price plan with vercel rather than anything about technology.